# How can I include pwd in the git-bash prompt

Tags: git-bash

I have tried adding  the following to .bashrc:

```
PS1="$(tty) \W>"
```

But this does not seem to work git-bash.

Comment: Try doublebackslash \\ or use `'simplequotes'`

Answer (score 2):

I changed the upper case /W to lower case /w. In Cygwin the upper case keeps only the last part of the path but it doesn't seem to work in git-bash. I now use the following:

```
PS1="$(tty) \w>"
```

After login in my home directory I get:

```
/dev/pty1 ~>
```

After cd to another directory I get:

```
/dev/pty1 /d/AngularProjects/angularapp>
```

Thanks to all